# Register multiple webhooks for single Twilio number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is it possible to programmatically register multiple webhook URLs for a single Twilio number? (When we receive an inbound SMS we would like multiple webhooks to be called with that data)

The [docs for "update an incomingPhoneNumber resource"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource#update-an-incomingphonenumber-resource) suggest that you can optionally set the `smsUrl`, but it's not clear how you would set *multiple* webhook URLs for a single number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not through the Twilio console options. You can write a Twilio Function that can fork out multiple outbound webhooks such as below, and then you just point the Twilio console to this Twilio Function.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('querystring');

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();

  let {
    ApiVersion,
    SmsSid,
    SmsStatus,
    SmsMessageSid,
    NumSegments,
    ToState,
    From,
    MessageSid,
    AccountSid,
    ToCity,
    FromCountry,
    ToZip,
    FromCity,
    To,
    FromZip,
    ToCountry,
    Body,
    NumMedia,
    FromState
  } = event;

  let requestBody = {
    ApiVersion,
    SmsSid,
    SmsStatus,
    SmsMessageSid,
    NumSegments,
    ToState,
    From,
    MessageSid,
    AccountSid,
    ToCity,
    FromCountry,
    ToZip,
    FromCity,
    To,
    FromZip,
    ToCountry,
    Body,
    NumMedia,
    FromState
  };

  let url1 = "https://example.com/1";
  let url2 = "https://example.com/2";

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  };

  Promise.all([
    axios.post(url1, qs.stringify(requestBody), config),
    axios.post(url2, qs.stringify(requestBody), config)
  ]).then(result => {
    callback(null, twiml);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    callback(err);
  });
};
```

Comment: This worked for me. I set the TwiConnect SMS service to use this function. I also had to make sure to add the `axios` and `qs` dependencies in the new Function Studio editor. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot register multiple webhooks for handling inbound SMS on a single number directly with Twilio Messaging. You can only define a single inbound handler and a fallback.

[image: Twilio Console messaging config]

One approach is to use an external service such as a proxy or specialized third-party solution to fanout the request to two or more additional endpoints.

Hookdeck is such a third-party service (who I work for at present). You can solve this problem by creating multiple [connections](https://hookdeck.com/docs/connections) that include the same Twilio [source](https://hookdeck.com/docs/sources) but use different [destinations](https://hookdeck.com/docs/destinations).

The following Hookdeck connection provides a single inbound webhook URL that you register with Twilio and then fans out the request to two handlers. More handlers could be added as required.

[image: Fanout of Twilio SMS messages to multiple handlers]

_note: this example also uses [transformations](https://hookdeck.com/docs/transformations) to convert the `content-type` and payload from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/json`.

The following screenshot shows:

- An inbound request from Twilio (the inbound SMS) resulting in multiple events being created, one for each Hookdeck destination
- The inbound request coming in as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

[image: Hookdeck Requests view showing a single request from Twilio resulting in multiple outbound events]

Please not that with any solution such as this, you won't be able to take advantage of [Twilio's TwiML response functionality](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply) that can instruct an SMS to be sent to the sender.